# What is the request code in PendingIntent in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I am trying to understand this code

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0);
```

I want to understand those parameters in Pending Intent
and what these lines of code will do

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a good question** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question lacks information for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: Right-click on `getActivity` and go to the method's declaration.

Comment: But it's not well  explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer parameter `requestCode` is a way to differentiate between multiple intents that have the same action, data, type, identity, class, and categories. Otherwise if you create a second intent with those same properties, even if the extras are different, it will not work.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent)

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by
>   the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This
>   means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the
>   PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have
>   been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same
>   kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data,
>   categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a
>   PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and
>   can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are
>   considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent.
>   A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
>   same ones defined by Intent#filterEquals(Intent). If you use two
>   Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent#filterEquals(Intent),
>   then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent#filterEquals(Intent), or different **request code** integers
>   supplied to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int),
>   getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int,
>   Intent, int), or getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

You are right by the way, the documentation on the specific parameter, *Private request code for the sender* is not very helpful in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I understood very well. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The request code is an arbitrary integer of your choosing in a given situation. When your Activity is created via the intent you can check the value of the request code to determine the source of the intent. There may be several cases that could lead to the Activity being created, and the request code is a means for you to tell the difference.